# What does it mean when residential demand is halfway faded?

Tags: simcity-2013

Just noticed that the green bars showing residential demand is actually partially faded out. The whole bar is filled, but a portion of the top is maybe 50% lighter than the rest. My industrial demand is also a full bar, but all the same color.

Anyone know what this means? Does it have anything to do with the region as a whole, or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means there is demand in your region, but not in the city (city demand is full green).

So your residential demand is at 50% locally and full regionally and you industrial demand is full within your city.

Comment: Note that if your industry is full with dark yellow and you zone industrial you'll get tons of commuters coming to your city = gridlock.

Comment: @user43524 A park and ride along with a bus stop at the entrance of your city can work wonders with that.

Comment: @James what does that do? Screen shot of working solution?

Comment: @Svish Sims will use public transportation for low to medium wealth jobs. I can not get to a screen shot right now as I am not near a system with the game installed.

Comment: @James with a full city zoned with ~1/3 Ind with 3 mines and a smelter + lots of education I was getting more population from commuters than locals! Note that ~35000 was being handled by train/boat/tram but that still left 5-10 thousand coming via road :(.